# Vertically center multiple boxes with CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to center vertically multiple boxes with different heights.

I dont know the height of the boxes as they are variable texts.

How can I do this with CSS (without having to use td and valign). Tried `display: table-cell` but it seems not compatible with IE

The image below shows the design, the post-it is the browser window

*removed dead ImageShack link*

Comment: how wide do you want the boxes to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not so elegant, but works. Create one-cell table. Only table has cross-browser vertical-align.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want the boxes to be fixed-width you can use the folling markup

```
<div class="vcontainer">
    <span>1<br/>2</span>
    <span>1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4</span>
    <span>1<br/>2<br/>3</span>
</div>
```

with these styles

```
.vcontainer {
    text-align: center;
}

.vcontainer span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The `inline-block` property [works in most modern browsers](http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/DisplayCSSProperty).

Comment: This is basically the correct way to do things. However, if you change the three elements to `<span>` instead of `<div>` then you get compatibility with even IE6! For Firefox 2 (if necessary), you can add `display:-moz-inline-box`.