# How to center img inside the div

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to center image inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237636/how-to-center-image-inside-div)

I need to be able to put the image in the center of the div.
My image needs to be in the center in whatever resolution.

Code:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:20%;">
    <img src="images/pic.png" id="image"  style="width: 208px; height: 75px;margin-left: 42%;" alt=""/>
</div>
```

This is not working as it should.

Comment: have you tried to set the margin of your img to auto?

Comment: Simple words in google gave me result with the above as the first entry.Google my friend.

Comment: @SvenBieder tried it and it's not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div style="width:100%; height:20%; text-align:center">
    <img src="images/pic.png" id="image"  style="width: 208px; height: 75px; margin:0 auto;" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Should work for ya

Comment: text-align:center was the thing that I need

Comment: yea sure..I needed to wait 10 min to accept :) sorry for that

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:20%;text-align:center;"> 
<img src="images/pic.png" id="image style="width:208px; height:75px; margin-left:42%;" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Sample
{
background:url(your_image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
height:200px;
width:200px;
}
```

(Assumes a div with id="sample" as you are already specifying height and width adding a background shouldn't be an issue)

Answer (score -1):

This is because you have a margin-left of 42% set to the image.
Try this on the image style:

```
display:block;margin:0 auto;
```

Comment: IE7,8,9, Firefox and Chrome do, what more do you need..