# How to center an image inside a div in the exact middle

Tags: css

I am trying to center an image inside a div in the exact middle - horizontally and vertically, but this is not working for me:

```
#col_as_table
{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:14%;
    min-height:100px;
    height:auto;
    display: table;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="col_as_table"><img src="test.png"></div>
```

Comment: And the rest of the code? could be helpfull to find the problem.. a jsfiddle example maybe

Comment: what kind of HTML element is the parent?

Comment: I have only that and inside i put the image

Comment: You put the image inside *what*? Not your CSS, I'd imagine.

Comment: Remove `float:left;` Why would you have float: left if you want to center the image ?

Comment: The div go to the left i have 2 cols and this it´s the col of left , only want show the image in the center and in the middle , i put the code i have

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div

Comment: You likely will not get any suitable answer untill someone makes the good guess. Just bring a fiddle or a codepen, witj 2 cols and some fake image and fake content with , eventually, a sketch of what you try to do. As said , there many ways to center content

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically center image inside div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237636/how-to-vertically-center-image-inside-div)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a shot. You'll need an extra div.

[Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/jCr7G/)

HTML:

```
<div class="divTable">
    <div class="innerDivTable">
        <img src="test.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.divTable {
    width: 200px; /* purely for demonstration */
    height: 200px; /* purely for demonstration */
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.innerDivTable {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mYj3/1/

CSS:

```
#col_as_table
{
   position:relative;
   margin: auto;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: table;
   height:500px;
}
img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; 
  left: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Again, this doesn't solve the OPs question. If you add a `height` property to the `div`, the image doesn't align vertically.

Comment: He doesn't have a height. He should clarify that in the question.

Comment: That's the problem. Before someone edited his question, he asked for vertical AND horizontal centering - even if the `height` of the `div` changes.

Comment: Ahh...Got it...My Bad!! I had no idea that was the case

Comment: No worries! I saw that part of the question was removed in an edit :)

Comment: Updated link and answer

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [Pen](http://codepen.io/magnus16/pen/GKcem) some time ago for the same purpose. It shows 3 methods on how you can center an image vertically as well as horizontally.

I'd personally use absolute positioning or table cell depending upon the situation.

```
#div3{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#div1 img{
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/C4DC7/

There are many ways to accomplish this. My example expands on the idea that you can afford your images to expand the parent `div` element.

Comment: This answer isn't correct. It fails in that the image is never in the exact center as the OP requested.

Comment: Yes also i can do that with padding but i want get the same as when i use for example in tables valign , i read time ago one way for do this in css with table but i can find

Comment: The question actually doesn't really deserve an answer. @disinfor I would not downvote answer but the question, maybe this is the right size of the picture of the op :)

Comment: @GCyrillus Fair enough! I think I can remove my down vote on the answer in a few minutes.