# Vertically center the text in my divs without affecting the JQuery

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

How can I vertically center the text in my divs without affecting the JQuery I have to equal all divs to the same height? I've been trying to add top 50 and left 50 but it's messing up the sizing on my divs.

In desperate need of vertical text!

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexisdeals/8fg28twb/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {
    maxheight = 0;
    $('.main article').each(function() {
      maxheight = $(this).height() > maxheight ? $(this).height() : maxheight;
    })
    $('.main article').height(maxheight);
  });

});
```

```css
/*Landing Page*/

#landingpage {
  margin-top: 2.5em;
}
.landingpagetable {
  margin-top: 2.5em;
  max-width: 56em;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}
.landingpage .main article {
  float: left;
  width: 29.33%;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 1%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: #d80000;
  min-height: 6.2em;
}
article.lp1 {
  /**/
  background-image: url(../../../wp-admin/images/cpr_lp_03.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
article.lp2 {
  background-image: url(../../../wp-admin/images/cpr_lp_04.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
article.lp3 {
  background-image: url(../../../wp-admin/images/cpr_lp_05.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
article.lp4 {
  background-image: url(../../../wp-admin/images/cpr_lp_07.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
article.lp5 {
  background-image: url(../../../wp-admin/images/cpr_lp_08.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
article.lp6 {
  background-image: url(../../../wp-admin/images/cpr_lp_09.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  .landingpage .main article {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .main article {
    background-image: none;
    min-height: 1em!important;
    max-height: 2em!important;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 1100px) {
  .landingpage .main article {
    width: 29.33%;
  }
  .main article {
    /*background-image:none;*/
    min-height: 9em!important;
    max-height: 9em!important;
  }
}
div#landingpage {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}
section.main #trial4444 p,
section.main #trial4445 p,
section.main #trial4446 p,
section.main #trial4447 p,
section.main #trial4448 p,
section.main #trial4449 p {
  display: none!important;
}
section.main #trial4444,
section.main #trial4445,
section.main #trial4446,
section.main #trial4447,
section.main #trial4448,
section.main #trial4449 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 0;
}
a:hover article.lp1,
a:hover article.lp2,
a:hover article.lp3,
a:hover article.lp4,
a:hover article.lp5,
a:hover article.lp6 {
  color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #d80000;
  /*adds zoom effect*/
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out
}
.landingpage .main article.lpfull {
  border: thin solid #d80000;
}
div#landingpage div.landingpage section.main h1 {
  font-size: 36pt;
  color: #d80000;
  text-align: center;
}
div.entry article.lpfull h1 {
  font-size: 36pt;
  color: #d80000;
  text-align: center;
}
article.lpfull p {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 2em;
}
article.lpfull {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="landingpage">
  <div class="landingpage">
    <section class="main">
      <h1>Find A Class</h1>
      <div id="trial4444">
        <a href="#">
          <article class="lp1">CPR &amp; AED Classes</article>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="trial4445">
        <a href="#2">
          <article class="lp2">CPR &amp; First Aid Classes</article>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="trial4446">
        <a href="#3">
          <article class="lp3">BLS Classes</article>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="trial4447">
        <a href="#4">
          <article class="lp4">EMSA Pediatric Classes</article>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="trial4448">
        <a href="#5">
          <article class="lp5">Instructor Training</article>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="trial4449">
        <a href="#6">
          <article class="lp6">Water Safety</article>
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<br>
<article class="lpfull">
  <h1>UPCOMING CLASSES</h1>
  [ESPRESSO_EVENTS_TABLE_TEMPLATE category_slug=current-classes order_by=event_name table_striping=false table_paging=false ]
</article>
```

Comment: The link is not working, please give a working demo.

Comment: It looks already vertical center. You are saying about text inside red div. right?

Comment: If you click run code snippet > Full Page, you will see large squares where the text is at the top instead of the middle. Yes text inside of div when the responsive squares get larger.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I've used before to accomplish vertical centering in CSS. This works in all the modern browsers.

```
<div style="display: table; height: 400px; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
      <div style="position: relative; top: -50%">
        any text<br>
        any height<br>
        any content, for example generated from DB<br>
        everything is vertically centered
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

[How to vertically center image inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237636/how-to-vertically-center-image-inside-div/34626206#34626206)

Answer (score 0):

For single line text you can always use line-height equal to the height of parent (). The text will align correctly center (vertical).

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately the responsive divs go from one line to three so it will not work in this case.